# Need advise in implementing ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I am trying to deploy from scratch something like BasicMenu example.

Steps are already done:

1. `ECSlidingViewController` created in storyboard with proper User Defined Runtime Attributes and set as init view.
2. `MenuViewontroller` created with identifier: `MenuView` and unwind method
3. `HomeScreenViewController` created with identifier: `HomeScreen` and rooted by `UINavigationController`
4. Created sliding segue from first cell in `MenuViewController.tableView` to `UINavigationController` of `HomeScreen`
5. In `HomeScreenViewController` created `UIBarButtonItem` with action binded to Unwind method.

After starting app all looks like Ok, but when I am tapping Menu button in the NavBar nothing happens. Also unwind method of `MenuViewController` not called.

P.S. I figured out that MenuViewController is not instantiated at runtime. No idea why =(
P.P.S. I found the issue!!! It was very stupid mistake - i am not appointed class to ViewController in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in appointment class to view controller in storyboard. It was by default UITableViewController instead MenuViewController.